# Mathf.Clamp not working, does not restrict values

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to restrict the movement (for now the z-axis) of my camera through the script attached to its pivot to the boundaries of a pool table and this is my script so far for testing.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class cameraManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    void Start()
    {

    }

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 cameraPos = transform.position;
        cameraPos.z = Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.z, -25, -4);

    }

}
```

but what happens is that when I move the camera pivot using the movement keys through a script in another object; the camera pivot is not restricted and just goes beyond the set clamp. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Transform.position`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-position.html) is a [**property**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) with a getter and a setter and [`Vector3`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html) a [struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct) and therefore a **value-type**.

You only use the **getter** to **return** and store a local `Vector3` but this is in no way aware or related to the `transform.position` anymore. It is a **copied** value.

Unless you assign something back to `transform.position` the **setter** is never called and thus whatever you do to the `Vector3` the getter **returned** has no effect in your scene at all

```
void Update()
{
    Vector3 cameraPos = transform.position;
    cameraPos.z = Mathf.Clamp(cameraPos.z, -25, -4);
    transform.position = cameraPos;
}
```